# Expectation calculation for $\mathbb E[X^2;X \le k]$

Tags: probability

Encountered this as one of the step of proving strong law of large numbers

Let $X$ be a r.v. such that $X\ge0$ a.s. and $\mathbb EX < \infty$

**Need to prove**: $$\mathbb E[X^2;X \le k]=\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{(x\le k)}2x\mathbb P(X > x)dx\,,\,where\,k\,is\,a\,positive\,integer$$

I tried the following, but I get results that are a bit off, could anyone help to point out what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

**My try**: $$\mathbb E[X^2;X \le k]=\int_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\le k\}}X(\omega)^2d\mathbb P(w)=\int_0^kx^2dF_X(x)=x^2F_X(x)|_{0}^{k}-\int_{0}^{k}2xF_X(x)dx$$
$$=k^2F_X(k) - \int_0^k2x(1 -\mathbb P(X>x))dx= k^2F_X(k) -x^2|_0^k+\int_0^k2x\mathbb P(X>x)dx$$
Thus, what I get is: $$\mathbb E[X^2;X\le k] = k^2F_X(k) - k^2 +\int_0^{\infty}1_{(x\le k)}2x\mathbb P(X>x)dx$$
There is no garantee that $F_X(k) = 1$, and thus what I get is a bit off from what is desired.  What went wrong in my deduction?

**EDIT**: some pointing out my prove is correct but the thing I want to prove is false. Just to make sure, the thing I want to prove seems to come from Real Analysis for Graduate Students (second edition) By Richard F. Bass. It is one step of Lemma 21.15. **The seem-to-be-false statement was extracted a bit by me just for simplification, but I might got wrong since it is not the exact original step.** Below is a picture from the book, and I highlight the step I'm have question about.[image]

**CONCLUSION**: See the discussion of answer by @pre-kidney, the author made a small mistake in his proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, your calculation is correct and the statement you are trying to prove is false. Here is a simple way to see why. 
$$
\int_0^{\infty}1_{x\leq k}\ 2x\ \mathbb P(X>x)\ dx=\mathbb E \int_0^{\infty} 1_{x\leq k}\ 2x \ 1_{x<X}\ dx.
$$
The integral inside the expectation is simply
$$
\int_0^{\min(X,k)}2x\ dx=\min(X,k)^2,
$$
so therefore the correct identity is
$$
\mathbb E\min(X^2,k^2)=\int_0^{\infty}1_{x\leq k}\ 2x\ \mathbb P(X>x)\ dx.
$$
To see how this is equivalent to your calculation, observe that
$$
\min(X^2,k^2)=X^21_{X\leq k} + k^2 1_{X>k},
$$
and therefore $\mathbb E\min(X^2,k^2)=\mathbb E[X^2;X\leq k]+k^2 (1-F_X(k))$.

**EDIT: Response to edited question**

This appears to be a relatively minor error in the book, which does not affect the proof. Simply replace the $=$ in the second line you have highlighted with $\leq $, and the proof continues unchanged.

In fact, we can pinpoint exactly how the mistake was made by the author. The equality in question was supposed to follow from Proposition 21.4 (not included in your screenshot), which states that if $X\geq 0$ and $p>0$ then
$$
\mathbb E X^p=\int_0^{\infty}p\lambda ^{p-1}\ \mathbb P(X>\lambda)\ d\lambda.
$$
The author was applying this to the random variable $X 1_{X\leq k}$ with $p=2$, which yields
$$
\mathbb E[X^2;X\leq k]=\int_0^{\infty} 2x\ \mathbb P(X\ 1_{X\leq k}>x)\ dx.
$$
Then, the author incorrectly replaced $\mathbb P(X\ 1_{X\leq k}>x)$ with $1_{x\leq k}\mathbb P(X>x)$. These expressions are not equal, in fact the precise relationship between them is that
$$
\mathbb P(X\ 1_{X\leq k}>x)=1_{x\leq k}\mathbb P(X>x)-1_{x\leq k}\mathbb P(X>k).
$$

Comment: Thanks pre-kidney. So maybe I'm perceiving a wrong statement, as that statement is not the original step. I've updated my question, supplying an original prove from the book, could you help to take a look?

Comment: See edit. It is a minor mistake in the book that does not affect the proof in question.

Comment: never mind, I guess I know the answer. That my proof is right, and the thing I want to prove is wrong. But the step in the book is still correct.
I've updated the question. So no issues.

Comment: Why do you think that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} F_X(k)=1$? I'm not sure your "resolution" is correct.

Comment: You are right, $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}F_X(k) = 1$, but the sum is not. See your updated EDIT, thanks @pre-kidney

Comment: Thanks, that's excellent explanation for why author applied this. Vote +1